# Can we use intents in Contextual Action Menu?

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, actionmode

I am trying to open another activity when a button is clicked from Context Menu Action Bar. But the application is force closing when i click the button.Can't we use intents in contextual action mode?

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item_id:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to call `startActivity()` from an `ActionMode`. Examine LogCat to see where your problem lies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: LogCat is showing NullPointerException, this is working fine when i use Context Menu,but not when i use Contextual ActionMode.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, please.

Comment: Found the problem, this helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors Thanks.